# Installing PHP 7.4 on macOS Sierra without brew?

Tags: php, macos, php-7.4

I am unable to find any info on installing PHP 7.4, all the info seems to go untill 7.3 but that has not been helpful.

What I have done so far is execute:

```
curl -s https://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.4
```

And this is the message I got:

[image]

It doesn't seem to install. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

If you check the script https://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh you can see it only support 7.3

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can install and upgrade to latest php version on mac without homebrew.
For me I use [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) a package manager for MacOS which is similar to [HomeBrew](https://brew.sh/) but more stable.

Example to upgrade to php74:

```
sudo port install php74
```

Install the extensions you need

```
sudo port install php74-cgi php74-gd php74-curl php74-intl php74-iconv php74-gettext php74-mbstring php74-imap php74-mcrypt php74-xmlrpc php74-mysql php74-openssl php74-sockets php74-zip php74-tidy php74-opcache php74-xsl php74-sqlite
```

Select php74 as the active PHP version. With this command you can have multiple php version and quickly switch from one to the other.

```
sudo port select php php74
```

Check which PHP binary is used (should return /opt/local/bin/php). Perhaps you may need to restart you terminal.

```
which php
```

Check the version (should return “PHP 7.4.XX (cli)…”)

```
php --version
```

Also, If you use XAMPP ensure to restart Apache Web server.

([Article Reference](https://gagarine.medium.com/install-php-7-3-cli-on-macos-mojave-using-macports-cbeb3a1b8d22))